# How to charge for web design and development?

Tags: payments, web-development

I've been learning CSS, HTML and JavaScript for front end dev and also started learning Bootstrap. I've had a few of my dads friends tell me they want a website for their business. The website would just have a home page, about, contact, and gallery. So I was planning on using a free Bootstrap template to use as a foundation but tweak it to their needs. Is $70 a good price?

Also, If I plan to do more freelancing should I bother learning Ruby on Rails, Django, PHP, etc?

Comment: 70$ per hour or 70$ for the whole project?

Comment: I voted to close this question. There's no way anyone can price your work for you, especially since we have no clue about the details of any project, your level of expertise, familiarity with tools, quality of work... etc. $70 per hour may be okay... $70 for an entire web site is **ridiculously low**.  (I mean **ridiculously**)

Comment: yeah i was going to charge $70 for the whole project since i would just be html and css and maybe some javascript

Comment: @NBera: Please don't do it. Prices like this will destroy the business for everyone.

Comment: @Apfelsaft so charge more...

Comment: I noticed one thing in reading the question, comments and answer.  There are no figures given, not even ballpark estimates, of what a web developer should be charging.  If I had to classify the question and answer I'd write something like:  info web: x$    business web: y$    social media: $  , etc.  This would be a good place to clarify and throw out some numbers of what people should expect as web developers.  Also, in those estimates I'd throw in used tools for creating those sites like ruby, php, html, css, etc.

Comment: @user6035379 as I posted in my comment above... it's *impossible* to even guess without full specifications of the site. In addition, a developer with 15 years experience isn't going to charge the same as someone in high school just starting. *That* is why there are no "figures" provided. **No one** can price **anything** for someone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have also been in the same situation as yourself when I started to learn web development. It seems that what your customers are wanting is a simple information website. In this case, the best case scenario would be to do your research into what freelancers normally charge. You can visit http://upwork.com or https://www.freelancer.co.uk to get a rough idea.

$70 seems like a relatively low price considering that things do not often go as planned.

The price also depends on the quality of your work - but if you are trying to get a few websites under your belt preparing you for bigger projects in future, then personally **I would take it.**

In fact, you'd be surprised that most clients often don't have a real indication of what to pay, so you have an upper hand here as long as you show confidence and are pro-active.

**Tip for your project:** stay organised and keep your head clear before you proceed to build anything (it saves you a lot of time!)

Answering your next question: It is important that you always invest in your skills - there is absolutely no harm in learning those different languages but it's always best if you specialise in one before moving on to the other. Multi-tasking can actually reduce productivity.

Best of luck

Comment: I would suggest **not** using upwork or freelancer to gage pricing. Those are **closed** markets that are often populated by workers in foreign countries where minimal payment is seen as "good" - and clients *looking* for the cheapest labor they can find.

Comment: @Scott Yes, i do agree to some extent with yourself. However, a rough indication will give an idea of what is out there.

Answer (score 0):

$70 is very cheap for a website, but if you are doing it for a friend and to get experience then go for it. Just don't expect to earn a decent living charging fees like that.

If you are looking at offering brochure style websites to clients, you should probably learn how to use a CMS such as Wordpress or my favourite, Orckestra (formally Composite C1).

Inevitably your client will want to change content themselves, and "most" business people still don't want to know how to change content themselves. Charging a fee for simply logging in to a website and changing some text is a good way to supplement your income.

As for what technology to learn, that's entirely dependent on who your target market is. For the standard blanket web development you'll a) run into lots of competition and b) be able to code it in whatever stack you like

Personally - My approach is to focus on some kind of niche. Integrations with Xero accounting system have worked well for me, as have NopCommerce customisations.

Answer (score -2):

Answering to your last question: it's best for you to learn ruby on rails or DJango. They will add lot more extra value to your freelance job field. 
In addition, always learn new things (language, framework, techniques, tools etc) if you want to stay in software development field.